# Can I get JSDoc-based Type Checking in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

I'd like to dip my toe in the water of Javascript static typing, by using JSDoc annotations to enforce type safety (yes I know about Flow/Typescript, but they're not really dipping a toe so much as doing a cannon ball into the pool).

However, the only tool I've found which can type-check my code from my JSDoc annotations is the Google Closure compiler, and I don't see any way to integrate that in to Webstorm (so that I can, for instance, see a red squiggly line the moment I assign a number to a string).

So, my question is, is there any way to make Webstorm "enforce" (draw squiggly lines under violations of) type safety, either by somehow incorporating the Google compiler or through some other tool?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is an RTFM situation: WebStorm has support for this out of the box (https://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2012/10/validating-javascript-code-with-jsdoc-types-annotations/).  However, it doesn't work "out of the box": you have to specifically enable it, install the Google Closure Compiler, tell WebStorm where it (and a config file for it) lives, etc.

Comment: It "just works" once you do all the steps you need to do to make it work :)

Good to know, thanks.